# UPI deep link issue with android app integration

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, deep-linking, upi

I am using native code for upi deep linking.
When  intent invoke on bhim app payment details page in not showing while other psp app redirecting to payment page
When I click a url from mobile browser like this upi://pay?pa=98955012345@upi&pn=abc&am=1 it opens BHIM app with pre-filled page of payee details.

However when I use my merchant app, to link it through intent deep-linking, it opens BHIM but does not redirect to pre-filled page.

Comment: Check this -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985944/upi-app-deep-linking-using-intent-inconsistent-and-buggy-behavior

Comment: Yes i followed this link but not getting intent response after transaction pay success.
In public void onActivityResult()

Answer (score 2):

It really works for the BHIM application also. Use this Code it works like a charm for every PSP enabled applications.

> Note: Instead of using the "%" better to use "+" to replace the white space from the URL. That works better.

```
private String getUPIString(String payeeAddress, String payeeName, String payeeMCC, String trxnID, String trxnRefId,
                        String trxnNote, String payeeAmount, String currencyCode, String refUrl) {
String UPI = "upi://pay?pa=" + payeeAddress + "&pn=" + payeeName
        + "&mc=" + payeeMCC + "&tid=" + trxnID + "&tr=" + trxnRefId
        + "&tn=" + trxnNote + "&am=" + payeeAmount + "&cu=" + currencyCode
        + "&refUrl=" + refUrl;
return UPI.replace(" ", "+");
```

}

Then pass the parameters in the method and pass the string to the Intent in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(UPI));
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
        }
```