# UPI integration in android: How to use onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android, python, kivy, upi

`UPI` (Unified Payment Interface) is a payment interface for Indian banks. 
In UPI transactions are links. Just like bitcoin transactions are messages
Those links are passed to UPI payment apps and the payer has to login to the app and click the pay button.

Our app has to start an intent and pass link to the UPI payment app and after payer clicks the pay button we need to call `onActivityResult`.
I dont know anything about android development in java.
I use python kivy for android development. I want to know what should my `onActivityResult` should do.

Sample code :
[UPI App Deep linking using Intent - inconsistent and buggy behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985944/upi-app-deep-linking-using-intent-inconsistent-and-buggy-behavior)

I can use java code in python using pyjnius.

Some reference link:
https://blog.deazzle.in/enable-upi-payments-in-your-app-without-the-need-to-integrate-with-a-bank-c911019f3b2d

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Should i assume that RESULT_OK will only be returned if payer clicks the pay button (zero knowledge about android development with java) if payer dont click pay button or just closes the app then RESULT_CANCELED will be returned???

Answer (score 1):

**Activity A:**

```
Intent start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PurchaseActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(start, 1);
```

And add this result listener:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //payment was successful
        }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //payment was canceled
        }
    }
}
```

And **Activity B:**
If payment was successful:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
finish();
```

or if it was canceled:

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
finish();
```

Comment: Actually Activity B is not my activity, it is a payment authorisation app which the user prefers. So, i dont hav any control over Activity B code.... 
So, should i assume that activity B will only return RESULT_OK if payment is done ??
If for some reason payment is not done then activity B will return RESULT_CANCELED??

Comment: @PrashantSingh It's based on activity. Try find source of it or anything like it and check if it returns RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELED. But if it's paynament activity, it probably have set up some result.

Answer (score 1):

you have not any need to do it manually. I have developed a library for it.
Just have to do a simple process.

```java
        final EasyUpiPayment easyUpiPayment = new EasyUpiPayment.Builder()
                .with(this)
                .setPayeeVpa("EXAMPLE@VPA")
                .setPayeeName("PAYEE_NAME")
                .setTransactionId("UNIQUE_TRANSACTION_ID")
                .setTransactionRefId("UNIQUE_TRANSACTION_REF_ID")
                .setDescription("DESCRIPTION_OR_SMALL_NOT")
                .setAmount("AMOUNT_IN_DECIMAL_XX.XX")
                .build();

        easyUpiPayment.startPayment();
```

For more info, you can visit below site.
https://github.com/PatilShreyas/EasyUpiPayment-Android

Comment: We cannot trust third party lib on upi payments.

Comment: Okay. Then you can refer source code to this. It'll be the same if you implement it your way.

Comment: This library has issues, no UPI found error coming for many users

Comment: it gives error like your app cross maximum transection limit .. why it is?? and what is solution ??