# What intent is used to open wallet app in android programming

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptocurrency

What intent should use to open wallet app(like blockchain, tronlink pro,...).

To open android market app we can use this:

```
"market://details?id=" + appPackageName
```

I want use an intent that show all wallet app installed on device.
Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985944/upi-app-deep-linking-using-intent-inconsistent-and-buggy-behavior

Comment: @Danialclarc thanks. but it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: have you found a solution to this ?

Comment: @RalucaLucaci Not yet bro.